# AngularDart - pub build "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Tags: upload, server, dart, angular-dart

I built my angulardart app using pub build, and uploaded the files to my server.
So the page is blank and the only error I get from the console is the following:

```
main.dart.js:10238 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

the chrome debugger points me to the following line in the main.dart.js file:

```
else (function(b){H.n0(F.mS(),b)})([])})})()
```

I triple checked my code and on my machine the build works fine. Any fixes?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't reproduce locally when you load the `pub build` output locally?

Comment: You could try to enable source maps using `- $dart2js:
    sourceMaps: true` in `pubspec.yaml` See also https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer
You could also try if you can reproduce using `pub build --mode=debug`. This way you get more readable code, but if the error is caused by minification, then it won't reproduce this way. At least you then know it's caused by minification.

Comment: What I basically did it took the files I used on my local machine, replaced the standard web folder with the one I got from running pub build and uploaded everything to my server. It works fine on my local machine, so it must have something to do with an incorrect configuration.

Comment: I also run into a similar problem recently, but wasn't able to fix it. Setting `minify: false` for `$dart2js` fixed it. That's not a satisfying solution though but in my case it doesn't matter currently.

Comment: Yep, I already tried building unminified. no success unfortunately. I'll keep looking for a solution. thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

`dart2js` should never produce syntactically invalid JavaScript. If you can share your source code or create a small example program that has the problem, please file an issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/new